# proving that huffman's algorithm can produce a codeword of length 1 when frequency greater than 0.40

Tags: algorithm, proof, huffman-code

If I have a set of symbols and frequencies: 
A - 0.1
B - 0.40
C - 0.2
D - 0.23
E - 0.15
F - 0.17

The Huffman algorithm will produce codewords that are only **greater** than length 1.

But when I change a frequency to be greater than 0.40, it will produce a codeword **of** length 1 and greater. How can construct a proof that proves that this is the case for any set of symbols, not just this one?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic and is best fitted for `cs.stackexchange.com` !

Comment: 0.4 seems sort of arbitrary so I doubt that's really something fundamental.

Comment: @harold Apparently, `0.4` is not arbitrary! (I was surprised)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Note that your frequencies don't add to 1; I'll assume it's a typo)

Here is a sketch of a proof that to make all codewords greater than 1 bit, no frequency can be greater than 2/5. [Without loss of generality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Without_loss_of_generality), the huffman tree must look like this:

```
    a+b+c+d (the sum must be equal to 1)
     /   \
  a+b     c+d
  / \     / \
 a   b   c   d
```

We must prove that all of a, b, c, and d are no greater than 2/5.

WLOG (again) a = b <= c <= d.

```
    2a+c+d
     /   \
   2a     c+d
  / \     / \
 a   a   c   d
```

Let's find the maximal value of `d` that is consistent with this Huffman tree. According to how the algorithm works, the following inequalities hold:

- a <= c
- a <= d
- 2a >= c
- 2a >= d

Let's also replace `c` by `1-d-2a`:

- a <= (1-d)/3
- a <= d
- a >= (1-d)/4
- a >= d/2

It's not immediately obvious how this constrains `a` and `d`, but you can easily plot the constraints in the `a`/`d` coordinate space. Then, you know which two of the above four inequalities are most important:

> d/2 <= a <= (1-d)/3

From here:

> d/2 <= (1-d)/3

So `d <= 2/5`.

Comment: Convincing, but.. surprising. I spent 10 minutes wondering why I couldn't construct a counter-example :)

Comment: Can you also give me an idea of how to prove that if some symbol in the set has frequency greater than 0.4, that huffman's algo will produce a codeword of length 1.

Comment: I don't think you proved whatever it was you thought you proved.  See my examples.

Comment: I understood the question this way: "if all codes are longer than 1, then *whatever*". You (probably) understood it in another way: "if one code has length 1, then *whatever*". It doesn't matter whether my understanding is correct, because it leads to a fun exercise.

Answer (score 0):

If you have three symbols with *any* frequencies, you will get one code of length 1 and two codes of length 2.  They could, for example, all have probability 1/3, which is less than 0.4.

Here is a simple counter-example to the assertion with four symbols and their probabilities resulting in a code of length 1, where all probabilities are less than 0.4:

```
a - 0.34
b - 0.33
c - 0.17
d - 0.16
```

It is easy to construct longer codes with the same property, by simply breaking up the probabilities.  E.g.:

```
a - 0.34
b - 0.33
c - 0.17
d - 0.08
e - 0.08
```